# SugarCRM, Is it possible to give edit options to some fields to users

Tags: sugarcrm

I have some different kind of issue here on SugarCRM.

As Admin I created a module named as "My Projects" where only "Project Manager" can edit/create or delete and the "designers" can only view this, this part is done.
   Now I created a custom field (dropdown field) as "Project Status" which should be available for everyone to edit (e.g Project Manager and Designers). 
  As designer, should not allow to edit any other options/fields in "My Projects" except the "Project Status" field.
   I am not sure whether it is possible to give edit option to certain fields instead of whole module.
  Please let me if anyone come across similar situations.

**Edit**
  I am using SugarCRM Professional version 6.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SugarCRM PRO/ENT you can define permissions on both module and field level.

- Go to Administration -> Role Management
- Select the role
- Click on a module to enter "field permissions" mode
- Click on the field you want to change
- Save when done

For more information, see SugarCRM [documentation](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarProfessional/6.1/-docs-Application_Guides-Sugar_Professional_Application_Guide_6.1.0GA-Administration.html#1916681).

Comment: Yes it works, First I set the edit permission and later disabled all individual fields edit is readonly except the editable field.